# Json media types for requests in Scala Spray

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json, spray-client

I have a simple json app. It works fine if I make a request like

> curl -X POST --data "userId=1" http://localhost:8080/register

But request fails when I try to make a json request, e.g.

> curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"userId"=1}' http://localhost:8080/register

```
> Content-type: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
< Server: spray-can/1.3.3
< Date: Mon, 07 Sep 2015 14:37:29 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<

Expected 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or Expected 'multipart/form-data'
```

How to ask Spray to process json request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curl command looks correct except for this part: `'{"userId"=1}'`. This is not a valid JSON document. It should be this instead `'{"userId" : 1}'`. I think that's why you getting this error.